# как сделать движение по окружности?

Tags: python, python-3.x, godot

я не понимаю как сделать движение по окружности в godot'е, если в python + pygame я мог сделать это таким образом:

```
def rotate_mouse(s,img,pos,num,num1):
    mouse_x,mouse_y=pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    rel_x, rel_y = (-screen_width//2+mouse_x-num+hero.x) - s.x, (mouse_y+hero.y+num1-screen_width//2) - s.y
    s.angle = (179 / math.pi) * -math.atan2(rel_y, rel_x)
    w, h = img.get_size()
    img2 = pygame.Surface((w*2, h*2), pygame.SRCALPHA)
    img2.blit(img, (w-w/6-pos[0], h-pos[1]))s.angle - это self.angle
s.angle - это self.angle
self.dotx=self.rect.center[0]+self.r*math.sin(math.radians(self.angle))
self.doty=self.rect.center[1]+self.r*math.cos(math.radians(self.angle))
```

и потом на точки self.dotx и self.doty поставить другой объект.

мне просто нужен аналог math.radians для godot'а.

и да этот объект будет вращаться от мыши, я это исправлю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё куда проще чем я ожидал.

```
var angle = 0
var r = 50
func _physics_process(delta):
    angle += 0.1
    if angle >= 360:
        angle = 0
    inp.y = r*sin(angle)
    inp.x = r*cos(angle)
    move_and_collide(inp)
```